# 1D zooming to point

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, graphics

I am building a ticker with JavaScript, and want to implement zooming to the cursor. I have a pan value and a zoom factor. I came up with the following code to come up with a new pan value given the current pan, the point to zoom to, and the old and new zoom values.

```
const panFromZoom = (pan, point, oldZoom, newZoom) => {
  return pan + point / newZoom - point / oldZoom;
};
```

This functions perfectly for cases in which `point` stays fixed at a certain value. When moving the point while actively zooming in or out, it results in unexpected behavior. What changes can I make to this  formula to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The ticker views time in seconds, so the way I reasoned through this is that I want the same pixel (the pivot point) to correspond to the same second value. The following ended up working.

```js
const panFromZoom = (pan, point, oldZoom, newZoom) => {
  const fac = newZoom / oldZoom;
  return point / fac + pan / fac - point;
}
```

What this formula is doing is transforming the normalized pan by the normalized point, then shifting it back using the unnormalized point.